# What resources do you use when developing a new course from scratch?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, teaching, coursework

I am in the process of developing two new state-of-the-art graduate courses. In the past five years I have been heavily involved in these fields and will use my own research and research from other relevant groups. I am also looking at new course developments in other universities.

Are there any other resources that you use when developing a new courses from scratch? Can anyone give me additional pointers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd go back and consult one of those "How to teach" books you've probably got lying around and focus on doing a good job of stating the course's **Learning Objectives**. Then, I'd make sure that the **course material**, **the learning activities** and **assessment tasks** are properly aligned with those objectives.

I would then make sure the students get to see those objectives and to understand how what they will be doing fits with those objectives.

I would design some sample assessment activities, such as sample exam questions (if that is one of your planned means of assessment). Then I would make sure that the content of your course is sufficient to enable students to do such assignments or answer such questions.

[Mckeachie's Teaching Tips](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mckeachies-Teaching-Tips-W-McKeachie/dp/1133940552/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1360919237&sr=1-1) is an excellent resource for helping you do this. And it never hurts to refresh your didactic skills.

Comment: I can't say how much I appreciate this. There are far too many courses that are built around content lists instead of teaching objectives (which I assume to be at least partially skill-based).

Comment: @Raphael: There are many resources on improving your teaching and preparing better courses. What's missing is time to read, absorb, and apply the knowledge.